# Is it possible to separate STDOUT context by its colour?

Tags: bash, colors, diff

I'm using the output of the excellent package `icdiff` (https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff) to check for differences between updated iterations of files. I'd like to parse out just the significant differences though. From the package `--help` I can't see any in-built options (and for full disclosure I've 'cross posted' at the github issues page to see if it can be added or I've missed something).

This has got me wondering whether a hacky solution might be to parse out the lines by their colour, since they are also colour coded by 'severity of difference'. Is this at all possible in `bash`? (Alternative approaches are welcome too!)

Here's a sample of the output (I can only think to add a picture here since the markup wouldnt show colour). I'd like to get just the lines where the whole line is solid red/green for instance. Excuse some of the screen wrapping, my monitor isn't wide enough and the text is small enough already.

[image]

Comment: So, as far as I understood your problem, you want to filter the stdout which is in green, right...???

Comment: does the icdiff utility still outputs color codes if output is not a tty? can you add a copy of icdiff command `| od -c | less` first lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with GNU Grep, for example

```
grep -Po $'\e\[31m\K.*(?=\e\[\d+m)'
```

to extract text in red,

- `\K` to keep the left outside match, like a lookbehind
- `(?=..)` lookahead assertion 0 length match

Answer (score 1):

you can grep on the ANSI escape sequences, e.g. (with 31 for red):

```
grep '^[\[31m'     # make the escape character (^[) by typing ctrl+v ESC
```

but you need to make sure your output stays colored if it is not sent to a terminal : (many programs will make their output B&W when output is not a terminal. - you can check it with less, which will show you the escape sequences)

Comment: This was the way i thought to do it. Is there a way to figure out how much text has been coloured? E.g. to differentiate between a whole red line vs one or two red characters?

Comment: You might use sed instead of grep and detect ^[[0m (or other), but it might get tricky if you have more than just 2 alternating colors.